# Relay does not turn off

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, relay

I am trying to control a 4-Relay module with my Raspberry Pi 4.
I tried to do that by writing this script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
relais_1 = 8
relais_2 = 10
relais_3 = 12

GPIO.setup(relais_1, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(relais_1, GPIO.HIGH)

time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(relais_1, GPIO.LOW)
```

However, the relay does not turn off after that. By changing it to this setting:

```
GPIO.output(relais_1, GPIO.LOW)

time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(relais_1, GPIO.HIGH)
```

It now works. But that does not make sense, does it?!  Hopefully someone will be able to explain this behavior so I can learn something..

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most relays are Active LOW - the relay is ON when the input is LOW and OFF when the input is HIGH.

The specification for your relay board should state this.

Comment: Ohh, right, thank you so much! In retrospective this was quite a stupid question I guess. But I really appreciate it. 
There was no information in the specification..

Comment: However, it is still behaving a bot oddly
without cleanup() at the end, every time I start it again it says "this channel is already in use" and it also turns on automatically even if I leave the "low" command out of it.

Comment: That is also normal just use GPIO.setWarnings(False) https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/